# How to sort from latest date and time in datatables

Tags: datatable, datatables, laravel-7

I had a problem on sorting my date and time in my datatable. The actual result of sorting is look like this.

```
Jan 13, 2021 12:03 PM
Jan 13, 2021 11:30 AM
Jan 13, 2021 09:03 AM
Jan 13, 2021 08:32 PM <-- Must be on top
Jan 13, 2021 06:33 AM
Jan 13, 2021 01:15 PM <-- Must be 2nd on top
```

The result did not sort based on the latest time. It sort based on the number regardless of AM and PM.

HTML Code

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="example" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
     <thead>
         <th class="text-center">Name</th>
         <th class="text-center">Date & Time Filled</th>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
          @foreach($users as $user)
          <tr>
              <td>{{ $user->name}}</td>
              <td>{{ date('M d, Y h:i A', strtotime($user->created_at)) }}</td>
          </tr>
          @endforeach
     </tbody>
</table>
```

my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example').DataTable( {
      "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]] //sort code
   });
});
```

controller code in laravel

```
$users:: User::latest('created_at')->get();
```

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the data - especially the datetime strings, so we can be sure what format they are using?

Comment: Also, there have been [many datetime handling questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+datetime+sort+datatables&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+datetime+sort+datatables) asked on SO for DataTables. Using the `moment.js` library is [one popular solution](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18).

Comment: ```2020-11-25 08:24:18```

Comment: ```2021-01-13 08:32:18```. The HTML format is like this {{ date('M d, Y h:i A', strtotime($user->created_at)) }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use the `moment.js` library, which can be included in your page as follows:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Then, for testing purposes I use the following test JSON data. This is stored in a JavaScript variable in my test, but could just as easily be loaded from the server, as you do in your question:

```js
var dataSource = [
  { "user": "Alfa", "created_at": "2021-01-13 12:03:00" },
  { "user": "Bravo", "created_at": "2021-01-13 11:30:00" },
  { "user": "Charlie", "created_at": "2021-01-13 09:03:00" },
  { "user": "Delta", "created_at": "2021-01-13 20:32:00" },
  { "user": "Echo", "created_at": "2021-01-13 06:33:00" },
  { "user": "Foxtrot", "created_at": "2021-01-13 13:15:00" }
];
```

My test table has two columns:

```html
    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>User</th>
                <th>DateTime</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Finally, my DataTables definition uses `moment.js` to create two versions of each date:

- a display date: `Jan 13, 2021 8:32 PM`
- a related sort date (the raw JSON data): `2021-01-13 20:32:00`

The `render` function in the DataTable uses the display date for displaying in the HTML table, and it uses the related raw date value for sorting.

```js
$('#example').DataTable( {
  "data": dataSource,
  "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
  "columnDefs":[
  { targets: 0, data: "user" },
  { targets: 1, data: "created_at",
    render: function ( data, type, row ) {
      var datetime = moment(data, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
      var displayString = moment(datetime).format('MMM DD, YYYY LT');
      if ( type === 'display' || type === 'filter' ) {
        return displayString;
      } else {
        return datetime; // for sorting
      }
    }
  }]
  } );

} );
```

The end result is:

[image]

---

**Update**

Assuming your data is already loaded into the HTML table (e.g. via Laravel) then your DataTables definition can be simplified.

```js
$('#example').DataTable( {
  "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
  "columnDefs":[
  { targets: 1,
    render: function ( data, type, row ) {
      var datetime = moment(data, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
      var displayString = moment(datetime).format('MMM DD, YYYY LT');
      if ( type === 'display' || type === 'filter' ) {
        return displayString;
      } else {
        return datetime;
      }
    }
  }]
  } );
```

Comment: Thanks, sir. I'll try that one but I need to revise a little bit because I'm not using JSON query. I'm using Laravel

Comment: Do I need to convert my results to JSON to able to do that?

Comment: You should be able to use your existing Laravel approach. But in that case, you will need to remove the `"data": dataSource,` line from my example. I need that line because I am using data from a Javascript variable called `dataSource`. Also, for the same reason, I think you will need to remove `data: "user"` and `data: "created_at"` - again, because your data will already be in the HTML table (not pulled from a JavaScript variable.

Comment: I added an example to the answer, which shows these changes.

Comment: It shows me an invalid date in that column

Comment: I got it. In my HTML I should do like this ```<td>{{ $user->created_at }}</td>``` instead of ```<td>{{ date('M d, Y h:i A', strtotime($user->created_at)) }}</td>```.

Comment: OK, great - glad you figured it out! (All of the date manipulation logic now happens in the DataTables code, so your Laravel code does not need to do anything special with the dates data.)